# TPrintDialog and reading orientation parameter

Tags: delphi, printdialog

Is there possibility to read from `TPrintDialog` orientation of page (horizontal/vertical) chosen by the user?

In classical solution:

```
if PrintDialog1.Execute() then
begin
  Printer.Orientation := poLandscape //I want read this parameter from PrintDialog

  Printer.BeginDoc;
  ...
  Printer.EndDoc;
end;
```

I can not find the orientation in `TPrintDialog`.

Comment: `TPrinterSetupDialog` offers the user a shortcut to those settings, but the component doesn't offer the settings either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TPrintDialog` does not offer that information. Rather it allows the user to select printer, print range, and number of copies.

When you show a `TPrintDialog` the user has the option of setting properties for their selected printer, including page orientation. You are then expected to read that information out of the `TPrinter` object that you you use to perform the printing.

Looking at your code, you are already using the global `Printer` object that represents the selected printer. This object already has the user's specified orientation. In other words, you can simply remove the line of code that attempts to assign to `Printer.Orientation` because that property has already been set.